# filter several data in several date mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

so i want to filter my buyer data who doing transaction in month 1,2,3 (jan-mar) 2019 who do the transaction too in month 4,5,6 (apr-june) 2017, so if the buyer doing transaction before apr 2017, the the buyer didnt appear in list, i've tried my syntax but idk why the result is so many, here's my syntax

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d1.buyer_id
FROM data_2019 d1 
WHERE
    MONTH (d1.tgl) IN (1, 2, 3) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data_2017 d2
                WHERE d2.buyer_id = d1.buyer_id AND d2.tgl < '2017-04-01')
GROUP BY
    buyer_id;
```

Can you tell me guys which the wrong at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there are two other problems, beyond what Tim Biegeleisen noted.

First, every sale by every buyer in `data_2019` will result in tests in `data_2017`.  I suggest querying from a table of all buyers, with an `EXISTS()` clause on `data_2019`.  This should also eliminate the need for the `DISTINCT` clause.

Second, partitioning the data into different tables by year will be a serious headache as time passes.  Why not put it all into a single table?

Thus:

```
SELECT 
    b.buyer_id
FROM buyer b
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data_all d
            WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND
                  d.tgl >= '2019-01-01' AND d.tgl < '2019-04-01') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data_all d
            WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND
                  d.tgl >= '2017-04-01' AND d.tgl < '2017-07-01') AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data_all d
                WHERE d.buyer_id = b.buyer_id AND
                      d.tgl >= '2017-01-01' AND d.tgl < '2017-04-01');
```

At this point, if you wanted to extend the "not before april 2017" clause to all years, you just remove the `d.tgl >= '2017-01-01'` clause, where you might otherwise need many `NOT EXISTS` classes for each year.

Answer (score 0):

I would express this using *two* `EXISTS` clauses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d1.buyer_id
FROM data_2019 d1
WHERE
    d1.tgl >= '2019-01-01' AND d1.tgl < '2019-04-01' AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data_2017 d2
            WHERE d2.buyer_id = d1.buyer_id AND
                  d2.tgl >= '2017-04-01' AND d2.tgl < '2017-07-01') AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM data_2017 d2
                WHERE d2.buyer_id = d1.buyer_id AND d2.tgl < '2017-04-01');
```

The first `EXISTS` clause asserts that the first query 2019 buyer also was active between April and June (inclusive) in 2017.  The second `EXISTS` clause makes sure that this same buyer also had no activity in the first quarter of 2017.